# How many cases of material failure were due to all three causes?

Tags: combinatorics

$100$
cases of material failure were investigated. In
$30$
of the cases the failure was due to just
faulty heat treatment, in
$40$
cases due to just excessive loading, in
$50$
of the cases to lack of
fatigue resistance. If
$7$
of the failure were due to two types of mechanism , how many were due to
all three?

Comment: I would start by drawing a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

I would look at the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). If you have any further questions please comment

Answer (score 0):

As @Vinyl_cape_jawa guided:
$$|A \cup B \cup C| = (|A| + |B| + |C|) - (|A \cap B| + |B \cap C| + |C \cap A|) + (|A \cap B \cap C|)$$
Now just substitute the given values.

Answer (score 0):

use the inclusion-exclusion principle to solve the question.
|H∪E∪R|=100
|H|=30
|E|=40
|R|=50

|H∪E∪R|= |H|+|E|+|R|-|H∩E|-|H∩R|-|R∩E|-|H∩E∩R|

Because 7 of the failures were due to two types of mechanism, there is only one intersection, therefore:

100= 30+40+50-7-|H∩E∩R|

100= 120-7-|H∩E∩R|

100=113-|H∩E∩R|

|H∩E∩R|=113-100

|H∩E∩R|= 13